# sqlite3 execute method returning empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, sqlite

I am writing a python program that uses `sqlite3`. It has a `shop` database in which it changes quantities in a table when items are bought. It updates the table correctly. However, when I am using a for statement to get a value it doesn't seem to recognise it and skips it.

Part of my code is as follows:

```
names = cursor.execute('''select Name from shop''')

numList = []
for name in names:
    num = int(input("How many " + name[0] + "s do you want? \n")
    numList.append(num)

print(numList)
```

It gives no errors, but doesn't add anything to the list.
I tried putting random stuff in the for statement to make it give an error but it still runs the script without errors.

It is like it is just ignoring the for statements completely. Any ideas what I might have done wrong?

Comment: You didn't use `fetchall()` to get the results of your query so there is nothing for it to iterate through. `names = cursor.execute('''select Name from shop''').fetchall()`

Comment: What is the shape of `names`? Check with `len(names)`

Comment: @roganjosh I added the fetchall but it still doesn't work. Still ignoring the for loop

Comment: Then you're getting an empty list of results. `print(names)`. How do you know that it updates correctly? Are you using `cursor.commit()` after inserting/updating your table? How have you verified that there's data in there? Try `"SELECT * FROM shop"` instead and see if anything happens in your `for` loop.

Comment: @roganjosh When I put cursor.commit it says cursor has no attribute commit

Comment: Bleugh, sorry. `connection.commit()` or `conn.commit()`. Whatever your connection to the database is called. If you INSERT/UPDATE your database, you need to `commit()` those changes, or the values don't actually exist. Note: you don't need to `commit()` anything that doesn't change the database itself (e.g. SELECT doesn't make any changes)

Comment: The code you've provided [works perfectly](http://ideone.com/ejtu21).  The error is, therefore, in the code you *haven't* provided. Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates the error. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: @roganjosh A cursor is directly iterable.

Comment: @CL. As I have since found out. This confuses me though. Is there a purpose of `fetchall()` specifically then? The 4 upvotes on my observation suggest that others are unaware of this too. Equally, I found out a while back you can execute queries on the `connection` but the docs just say this is "non-standard"; which doesn't explain too much.

Comment: `fetchall()` creates copies of all returned rows; Iterating over the cursor fetches (and in the best case, computes) the rows one by one without having to store previous rows anywhere.

Comment: @roganjosh When I put database.commit() after all places I edited the database it worked! Thanks.